# Android importing issue.

Tags: android

Hey Guys i'm having a few issues with I think importation. I'm getting the error message:`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method show(FragmentManager, String) from the type DialogFragment"`  under `MyDialog.show(manager, "MyDialog");`

Anybody know what it means? I'm thinking some issue with importing but i'm not to sure.

Rest of code:

```
package com.example.sub_assignment1_2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * 
 */
public class FragmentB extends Fragment implements MyDialog.Communicator {

    public FragmentB() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public void showDialog(View v)

    {
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
            MyDialog myDialog=new MyDialog();
            MyDialog.show(manager, "MyDialog");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDialogMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

    }

}
```

I'm also having an issue under `Toast.makeText(this, message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` The displayed error is: `Toast.makeText(this, message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` Which i'm also thinking is an import error?

If anybody could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your importing is spot on, it's just the actual usage, particularly from within a fragment.

For the dialog: Use myDialog.show() instead of MyDialog.show()

For the toast: You have to get the activity OR application context. IE, instead of passing it "this" [which is a fragment and not an activity], pass in, for example, "GetApplicationContext()". "GetActivity()," etc. As a side note, Toasts can take either application or activity contexts due to their nature.

Comment: Ok but i'm trying to parse in a seperate java file called myDialog does that count as an activity?

Comment: To put it simply: If that separate java file doesn't extend Activity [or any other form of the class Activity], then no it's not an activity

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first error: You need to call `myDialog.show()` instead of `MyDialog.show()` to call the instance's method instance of trying to call a static method.

Regarding your second error: use `getActivity()` instead of `this` (`DialogFragment` does not implement `Context`).

P.S. In the future, please make separate questions.

Comment: So something like this?: FragmentB.this.getActivity();

Comment: Yeah, but you should just be able to call `getActivity()`.